# How to get data from TextArea to save it in Winword and notepad?

Tags: javascript, html, vbscript, hta

For part of my scripting assignment, I need to create an html form that allows the user to enter data into a text area that can then be saved as either a Word or Notepad document in the :H drive. using HTA. The HTML form part was very easy but I'm struggling with getting it to work so that clicking on either button saves the data in the correct place. So far I've been working on getting the first button for saving the file in Word to work first but I'm frankly at a loss as to where to go from here. Here is the code I have so far:

```
<html>
<head>
<HTA:APPLICATION>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
function SaveFile()
{
wordApp = new ActiveXObject("Word.Application");
wordApp.Visible = true;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
Enter your information:
<br />
<textarea cols="40" rows="12">
</textarea>
<br />
<input type="button" value="save into word" id="Word.Application" />
<input type="button" value="save into notepad" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Could I get some help with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well you are missing an event which triggers an action. In this case 'onClick'. Whereby 'onClick' would call your SaveFile function. I would advise having a generic save function whereby depending on what value is passed to the SaveFile function would determine which application is used to save your data (you can use one of the conditional structures for this).

```
 onClick="SaveFile('notepad')" //saves data in notepad

 onClick="SaveFile('word')" //saves data in word
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try for this HTA :

```
<html>
<Title>Save file into noteapd and Word Application</Title>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="MSThemeCompatible" CONTENT="YES">
<head>
<HTA:APPLICATION 
ICON="Notepad.exe"
APPLICATIONNAME = "Save file into noteapd and Word Application" 
BORDER="dialog"
BORDERSTYLE="complex"
>
</head>
<script type="text/Vbscript">
'*****************************************************
Sub window_onload()
    CenterWindow 500,350
End Sub
'*****************************************************
Sub CenterWindow(x,y)
    Dim iLeft,itop
    window.resizeTo x,y
    iLeft = window.screen.availWidth/2 - x/2
    itop = window.screen.availHeight/2 - y/2
    window.moveTo ileft,itop
End Sub
'*****************************************************
Sub Save2Word()
'Create and Save a Word Document
Title = "Data saved into Word Appplication"
FileDoc = "C:\" & Month(Date) & "_" & Day(Date) & "_" & Year(Date) & ".doc"
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = False
Txtarea = document.all("Txtarea").Value
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add()
Set objSelection = objWord.Selection
objSelection.Font.Name = "Comic Sans MS"
objSelection.Font.Size = "12"
objSelection.TypeText Txtarea
objDoc.SaveAs(FileDoc)
objWord.Quit
MsgBox "Data saved into : " & FileDoc,vbInformation,Title
End Sub
'*****************************************************
Sub Save2Notepad()
'Save into a Notepad Document
Title = "Data saved into Notepad Appplication"
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
FileTxt = "C:\" & Month(Date) & "_" & Day(Date) & "_" & Year(Date) & ".txt"
Txtarea = document.all("Txtarea").Value
Set oFile = fso.OpenTextFile(FileTxt,8,true)
oFIle.WriteLine Txtarea
oFile.Close
MsgBox "Data saved into : " & FileTxt,vbInformation,Title
End Sub
'*****************************************************
</script>
<body>
<center>
<form>
Enter your information:
<br>
<textarea ID="Txtarea" NAME="Txtarea" cols="40" rows="12"></textarea>
<hr>
<input type="button" value="save into word"    onClick="Save2Word()"/>
<input type="button" value="save into notepad" onClick="Save2Notepad()"/>
<hr>
</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```